# How do I import a variable from outside my class?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables

Simplest way I can describe my problem:

I have a list generated from a separate function outside of my main class. I need to use this same list in a method in my class, but I don't know how to import the list so I can use it in my class.

Both the separate function and class are in the same file, and I cannot instead write that function in my class.

How would I be able to use this list within my class?

Comment: If it's a global variable in the module, you can just write the variable's name anywhere within the module… A minimal code sample that illustrates the problem better would help here.

Comment: Can you not simply call the function inside the class, and capture its return value, i.e. make a method that wraps this function from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ways to go about this.

#### 1. Initialize the class with your list.

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def func(self):
        print(self.array)


array = [1, 2, 3]
t = Test(array)
t.func() # > [1, 2, 3]
```

#### 2. Global Scope

```
class Test(object):
    def func(self):
        print(array)


array = [1, 2, 3]
t = Test()
t.func() # > [1, 2, 3]
```

#### 3. Adding to Class Scope

```py
class Test(object):
    def func(self):
        print(self.array)


array = [1, 2, 3]
t = Test()
t.array = array
t.func() # > [1, 2, 3]
```

All of these have drawbacks, however.

1. Every class must be initialized with an array.
2. If array is modified outside, it is modified inside the class.
3. Similar to #1, but array is not initialized with the class.

Proper object-oriented programming calls for you to do #1, as you explicitly define the variables and context of the objects. It also creates the pretext for you to write functions relating to the passing variables *within* that object.

Comment: I think #2 will generate a "used before defining" error.

Comment: @MarkRansom I made sure to test these out in the interpreter before posting :)

Comment: For #2, both `array = [1, 2, 3]; t = Test(); t.func() ` and `t = Test(); array = [1, 2, 3]; t.func()` will work. You can see why when we do `print(globals())`, which will contain our `array` in there. `func()`, therefore, will utilize that global variable to print the `array`.

Comment: I always thought the variable had to exist when the function was defined, not when it was used.  I know there are traps you can fall into if that's not the case.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's the case for functions/class initialization since they are only put in the `global` scope _after_ their initial declaration is read by the interpreter. In order words, calling/initializing a function/class on line 1, but defining it on line 2 will give you an error. If you think of the `global()` scope being that of the linear scan of the document from top-to-bottom, you can prevent these errors quite easily (in the case of my example above the function _call_ is always _after_ the _variable declaration_). Hopefully, that expands on the topic a bit. :)